# Nonzero ideals in a discrete valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory

We say that $K$ is a discrete valuation field if there exists a surjective map $v:K\to\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that

1. $v(xy)=v(x)+v(y)$
2. $v(x+y)=\inf\{v(x),v(y)\}$
3. $v(x)=\infty$ if and only if $x=0$

We then define the *discrete valuation ring* to be $A=\{x\in K\mid v(x)\geq 0\}$.

I am trying to show that if $A$ is a discrete valuation ring, and $m=(\pi)$ with $v(\pi)=1$, then all ideals in $A$ are of the form $(\pi^n)$ for some $n$. Now one way to do this is to show that $A$ is noetherian and to invoke Krull's intersection theorem, but neither have been discussed in class, so I'm wondering: is there a way to show this directly?

Comment: What is your definition of a discrete valuation ring? There are many equivalent definitions, so it is unclear what you mean by "showing directly".

Comment: Thanks, I edited the first post accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

This results from the fact that if $x\in A$ is such that $v(x)=n>0$, then we can write
$$x=u\pi^n,\quad\text{where }u \text{ is a unit in }A.$$

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this argument use Krull's intersection theorem? Or can you prove this directly?

Comment: It results only from the properties of a valuation.

Comment: Okay, I will try to prove it directly then, thanks!

Comment: Freel free to ask if you meet any difficulty.

Comment: Here's an attempt. Suppose $x$ has valuation $v(x)=n$. Then $v(\frac{x}{\pi^n})=0$ which means $\frac{x}{\pi^n}=u$ where $u$ is a unit. Does this work?

Comment: It's exactly that. You might add that by definition of the ring of a valuation, it belongs to $A$.